# comparators in sort function and priority queue c++

Tags: c++, comparator, priority-queue, min-heap, max-heap

In C++ Sort function, the third optional parameter is a comparator used to sort the objects. If we pass in less as the comparator, we will get objects in increasing order. (if the comparator is evaluated to be true, the positions won't be changed, otherwise elements will be swaped!)  Is my understanding correct?

Following the same fashion, if we pass a less comparator to priority queue, we should get a min-heap,(if the underlying data structure is chosen to be vector, objects are sorted in increasing order. If we call top(), the first element of vector will be returned, which is the smallest number. Therefore, I think it is a min heap) why do we get a max heap?

Comment: The first part of your statement is correct. However to get a min heap you'd need to pass `std::greater` otherwise by default `std::less` creates max heap behavior. This is stated in the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

Comment: Note that the assumption that returning true leaves the order unchanged is not valid. The two items are not required to be passed in the same order as their appearance in the original vector.

Comment: `std::priority_queue` is simply a max heap by default. There isn't really more to explain.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this online documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue), the C++ library class `std::priority_queue` returns the *largest* element first in the sense that the comparator orders smaller elements before larger elements. From above link:

> Note that the Compare parameter is defined such that it returns true
>   if its first argument comes before its second argument in a weak
>   ordering. But because the priority queue outputs largest elements
>   first, the elements that "come before" are actually output last. That
>   is, the front of the queue contains the "last" element according to
>   the weak ordering imposed by Compare.

Thus `std::priority_queue<T,std::less<T>>` makes a max-heap and prioritizes larger elements.